# What is the IPA for the Russian word “разные”?

Tags: произношение

Do you know what the IPA for the Russian word “разные” is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever the standard IPA is, the actual pronunciation is such that the ending of this word is barely distinguishable, at least in the Moscow dialect. If I say "разные" in a sentence, you will not be able to tell which sound I use at the end of this word. You will have to figure out the implied ending from the rest of the sentence.

A couple of centuries ago this word was written as "разныя", with я at the end. And I do not think that the pronunciation of this word was really different from what it is now. Phonetically, it is hard to tell whether it is pronounced as ыя or ые, as long as the ending is not stressed.

If you try to pronounce the ending of this word distinctly, you will sound unnatural regardless of your choice of the IPA.

I usually say the phrase "разные люди" as ['raznɨ'lʲʉdʲɪ] or ['raznə'lʲʉdʲɪ], sometimes with a micropause before л, but some native speakers may say ['raznɨɪ'lʲʉdʲɪ], ['raznɨj'lʲʉdʲɪ], ['raznɨjɪ'lʲʉdʲɪ], ['raznɨə'lʲʉdʲɪ], or even ['raznəjə'lʲʉdʲɪ], and I myself sometimes say anything from this list. There is no real difference in perception by the Russian mind, and it is usually hard to tell how the speaker pronounced the ending in разные. The implied ending is generally obvious from the sentence as a whole.

Comment: It is exactly IPA that the OP is asking about and not the way you think you pronounce the word "in a sentence".

Comment: @YellowSky I think different IPA exist for this word. Wiktionary says ['raznɨjɪ̯], and your tool says ['raznɨjə]. I think the cause is the indistinct pronunciation I am talking about. I think the OP wants to know how this word is actually pronounced. My answer explains this.

Comment: Would you tell me, where does Wiktionary say "разные" is ['raznɨjɪ̯]?

Comment: @YellowSky I see now I was redirected from разные to разный and did not notice it. Anyway, I do not consider your tool as a source of indisputable truth. People do pronounce разные as разныи, разны, разныэ, and so on, and it is usually hard to tell how the speaker pronounced. I think various IPA are all correct. The most important thing is that if the OP pronounces the ending very distinctly, he will sound unnatural regardless of the chosen IPA.

Comment: Obviously, the OP wants to know the sound at the end of the word. What he does not realise is that whatever sound he chooses, he will sound the same to the Russian mind as long as he keeps the ending short and unstressed .

Answer (score 1):

The IPA for the Russian word “разные” is /ˈraznɨjə/.

You can use the [Russian pronunciation tool - phonetic transcription translator](https://easypronunciation.com/en/russian-phonetic-transcription-converter#phonetic_transcription) to get the IPA for *any* Russian word, and even for a whole text, it produces reliable transcription. There's no need to ask a separate question here for every word you'd like to be transcribed.